# Record method duration with points in time, using micrometer/prometheus?

Tags: java, microservices, micrometer

Is it possible to record method durations and store them together with a timestamp, using micrometer or prometheus? I didn't find anything about that. I have a microservice, where one of the methods is called about 50 times a day. Sometimes, method duration is unexpectedly high and I'm trying to track down, where it comes from.

Greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can record method durations and store them together with a timestamp using Micrometer or Prometheus. Both tools are commonly used for monitoring and tracking performance metrics in microservices applications.

**Using Micrometer:**

Create a custom timer metric for the method whose duration you want to record. You can do this in your method or a surrounding aspect.

```
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.Metrics;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.Timer;

public class YourService {
    private final Timer methodExecutionTimer;

    public YourService() {
        methodExecutionTimer = Metrics.timer("your_service.method_execution_time");
    }

    public void yourMethod() {
        Timer.Sample sample = Timer.start();
        // Your method logic here
        sample.stop(methodExecutionTimer);
    }
}
```

To configure Micrometer to export metrics, you typically need to specify a registry and configure that registry to export metrics to a specific monitoring system.

**Using Prometheus:**

Create custom metrics for your method durations and expose them as HTTP endpoints for Prometheus to scrape. Here's an example of how you can do this:

```
import io.prometheus.client.Counter;
import io.prometheus.client.Histogram;
import io.prometheus.client.exporter.MetricsServlet;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

@WebServlet("/metrics")
public class PrometheusMetricsServlet extends MetricsServlet {
    // Create a histogram to record method durations
    static final Histogram methodExecutionTime = Histogram.build()
        .name("method_execution_time")
        .help("Method execution time in seconds")
        .register();

    // Create a counter for tracking method invocations
    static final Counter methodInvocations = Counter.build()
        .name("method_invocations_total")
        .help("Total number of method invocations")
        .register();

    // Your method to record
    public void yourMethod() {
        try (Histogram.Timer timer = methodExecutionTime.startTimer()) {
            // Your method logic here
            methodInvocations.inc();
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure to configure your microservice to expose the /metrics endpoint, which Prometheus will scrape.